# Making strlcpy available in linux

Tags: linux, gcc, freebsd, glibc

I'm trying to compile a source code which was originally written for `FreeBSD` and since [strlcpy isn't included in the linux GlibC](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/nonstandard/strlcpy#Criticism) , I'm now stopped at this stage.

GCC has suggested that I can use [strncpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) but I don't want to actually change the source code.

Do I need to re-compile my LibC ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you include proper headers? https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy

Comment: @KamilCuk The problem is here : in the BSD the "bsd/" part in the "#include <bsd/string.h>" is not necessary ( in fact forbidden) . But I haven't the BSD's version of the string.h . So I'm looking for a way to install it.

Comment: So where I can find the BSD version of string.h  and put it somewhere and at the end add some flags to the "CFLAGS" of the makefile ?

Comment: Don't you have `/usr/include/bsd/string.h`? Then install them using you linux distribution package manager. On my archlinux it's owned by `extra/libbsd` package.

Comment: @KamilCuk No I haven't the bsd/ directory at all. What package does contain it ? in ubuntu preferably.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi: You can use `apt-file` to find out which (uninstalled) package contains a file. It's very useful.  `apt-file search /usr/include/bsd/string.h` reports that the file is in the package `libbsd-dev`, just as Ismael's answer says.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks Nate. That's a nice method to search through packages based on filenames . You can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution to port BSD applications is [libbsd](https://libbsd.freedesktop.org/wiki/); and it's already packaged for most systems.

On Debian-based systems the development package is named `libbsd-dev`.

You can compile unmodified BSD source code by adding the following to your CFLAGS:
`-DLIBBSD_OVERLAY -I/usr/include/bsd`, and linking with `-lbsd`.

However, instead of hardcoding those values, you should use `pkg-config` with the `libbsd-overlay` package if you intend to distribute your build system.

Comment: Here's what worked for me on Ubuntu to compile a program `c.c`: `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libbsd-overlay) c.c -o c $(pkg-config --libs libbsd-overlay)`

Answer (score 3):

You can download source code from https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/libkern/strlcpy.c and add it with 2 modifications to your source code:

```
$ diff strlcpy.c strlcpy.c.orig 
20c20
< //__FBSDID("$FreeBSD$");
---
> __FBSDID("$FreeBSD$");
23c23
< //#include <sys/libkern.h>
---
> #include <sys/libkern.h>
```

I have compiled successfully this function with gcc 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I use ubuntu 18.04 server with gcc 7.5 too . Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using any version of a string copying function written in C. This is one of the last refuges of things that ought to be hand written assembly.