# unable to test the non standard function strlcpy

Tags: c

I am trying to create my own implementation of `strlcpy` but first, I wanted to test the original function.

When I try to compile my code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ft_strlcpy.c`, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaTaHki.o: in function `test':
ft_strlcpy.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `strlcpy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code sample for testing the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bsd/string.h>

void test(int size)
{
    char string[] = "Hello there, Venus";
    char buffer[19];
    int r;

    r = strlcpy(buffer, string, size);

    printf("Copied '%s' into '%s', length %d\n", string, buffer, r);
}

int main()
{
    test(19);
    test(10);
    test(1);
    test(0);

    return (0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong how can I test it?

Comment: This seems different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998682/making-strlcpy-available-in-linux, but that might be because we don't see all the error output.

Comment: How do you build?

Comment: i did what they said in that question and now i get this `error: no include path in which to search for string.h` #include_next <string.h>

Comment: @Gerhardh you mean the command i use to compile ?

Comment: You're probably not linking the correct library.

Comment: Yes, if you add more functions you also need to tell the linker to use that library

Comment: @Shawn i tried with the `#include <string.h>` and `#include <string.h>` both dont work

Comment: @Gerhardh `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ft_strlcpy.c`

Comment: Those are headers, not libraries.

Comment: Where did they recommend `#include_next`?  In your comment above you have the same include twice.

Comment: In the linked question they suggest to use `pkg_config` to set values like `-DLIBBSD_OVERLAY -I/usr/include/bsd` and also to use `-lbsd`.

Comment: @Gerhardh when i tried this command from the question `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libbsd-overlay) ft_strlcpy.c -o c $(pkg-config --libs libbsd-overlay)`

Comment: @Shawn sorry how can i do the linking if i dont have a library.h file ?

Comment: You are mixing 2 different messages. In your question you mention an error due to unresolved reference. That means you could compile and did not miss any header. But you did not specify proper library. That other message "no include path..." doesn't seem to match with yor code. You include `bsd/string.h` not `string.h` Also if that was an issue you could never get to that first error message from the linker.

Comment: Please update your question with the real code and your compilation command.

Comment: Also note that in you case you use `-pedantic`/`-pedantic-errors`, gcc will filter out all non-standard crap from standard headers since C compilers aren't allowed to store non-standard extensions in them. In practice this is probably just an issue in POSIX environments - POSIX has a nasty habit of colliding with standard C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to compile my code with gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
> ft_strlcpy.c, I get this:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaTaHki.o: in function `test':
> ft_strlcpy.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `strlcpy'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

That is a linker error, indicating that the function you are trying to call is not found in your code or in any of the libraries being linked, including the C standard library.

Having recognized that, [the (Linux) manual page for `strlcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy) quickly yields a probable reason and solution where it says, near the top:

> ### Library
>
> Utility functions from BSD systems (libbsd, -lbsd)

Supposing that that documentation is relevant to you, which it probably is if you are compiling with `gcc`, it tells you not only what library but exactly what link option to use: `-lbsd`.  Therefore, compile your code this way:

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror ft_strlcpy.c -lbsd
```

That works for me.

Comment: thank you i just had to install the libbsd-dev and upgrade my terminal  now its working just fine

Answer (score 0):

Your quick test is somewhat unreliable because `buffer` is uninitialized so the output is unpredictable for the last test.

Here is a modified version with more explicit output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(int size) {
    char string[] = "Hello there, Venus";
    char buffer[20] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    int r = strlcpy(buffer, string, size);
    int len = strlen(buffer);

    printf("Source: '%s', size: %d, buffer: '%s', len: %d, result: %d\n",
           string, size, buffer, len, r);
}

int main() {
    test(19);
    test(10);
    test(1);
    test(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Source: 'Hello there, Venus', size: 19, buffer: 'Hello there, Venus', len: 18, result: 18
Source: 'Hello there, Venus', size: 10, buffer: 'Hello the', len: 9, result: 18
Source: 'Hello there, Venus', size: 1, buffer: '', len: 0, result: 18
Source: 'Hello there, Venus', size: 0, buffer: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', len: 19, result: 18
```